# How can I generate every possible integer in a range without repeats from a seeds that is also reversible

Tags: python, random, input

I have been looking for a while at large number generation through seeds and I’ve struggled to find what I am looking for due to how specific it is. I think the main thing that is causing the problems is the size of numbers I want to generate, for example... I want to have it so that I can generate every single number that is 5000 digits long through some form of seed or selective input process. The other problem being that I would like to be able to reverse the process to know how I got there. If I have this number I want to know what inputs or what seed would generate this. Hope this makes sense and I understand this is a extremely specific question.

Comment: Generate them in order and shuffle randomly

Comment: I can not do that because I am trying to make more than 10^8000 numbers. If I were to do that we wouldn’t have enough storage on this planet to store all the numbers so I could shuffle them. It has to be like Minecraft seeds in a way. All possible but not all there

Comment: Do you want for each seed a sequence or just *ONE* number? If the latter and reversible, then the count of input seeds must be the same as the count of output numbers, and it is unclear why they cannot be the same.  
If the former, when it is unclear what you mean by reversible, examples may help.

Comment: In this case a sequence OR just one number would work. If it were a sequence I would need probably thousands of 3 digit numbers. The reason the input seeds cannot be the same as the output of numbers is because of the length of the numbers I am generating. To generate every single one of those numbers with and exact seed while keep the order random and not repeating is something I am unsure whether it’s possible and in my attempts it hasn’t been but this may be from my lack of expertise.

Comment: What do you mean with reverse the process? I knew of a solution that lets you randomly iterate through all permutations without repeats forwards or backwards.

Comment: You may get a non-repetitive sequence in an arbitrary dimension 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence . Yet you need to move from reals to integers. 
Another approach, you may generate any sequence of (short, different) seeds and then encrypt them through a reversible chiper to fixed-size codes (quasirandom long numbers).

Comment: @camel-cdr I mean I want to just have the result and know what inputs were put in to get it or what the seed was to generate it

Comment: @AskoldIlvento Thank you for that information I will do some research and testing and let you know if it worked or not

Comment: After some research I’m really confused on what I am reading and it could be correct I’m just not smart enough to understand what I’m reading.

Comment: I don't think you fully comprehend the volumes you're talking about. You write: *I am trying to make more than 10^8000 numbers...* but that is an absurd number. For example my computer only has about 10^10 bytes of ram.

Comment: I understand what number size I am working with as I am obsessed with large numbers. I know I’m asking a hard question and trying to find a medium answer so I’m not in the best situation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a problem like this I would use an encryption. Since encryption is a one-to-one process provided you use unique inputs, and keep the same key, then the outputs are guaranteed unique. for unique inputs, encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... You will need to extend the inputs by adding leading zeros so they are the size you need, enough for the binary equivalent of 5,000 decimal digits.

The output from the encryption will be the same size. Just convert the binary output back into the equivalent decimal number. There may be a few boundary cases just over the limit where the decimal and binary boundaries; in those cases just re-encrypt until the result is within the set limit. This is the cycle walking technique from Format Preserving encryption.